# Comiple time error while implenting inheritance in parametrized generic class [tuple ]

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, tuples

In the below code line **Orange[Integer,String] orange=new Orange<>(45, "child");**  throws an error saying **Type mismatch: cannot convert from Orange[String,Integer] to Orange[Integer,String]**

Is their any rule while passing argument to parametrized generic class or have i committed any syntactic mistake?

```
package generics;
    class Fruits<P>{
        private P parent;
        public Fruits(P parent) {
            super();
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void name(){
            System.out.println("i am Fruit class witha value of "+parent);
        }
    }
    class Orange<C,P> extends Fruits<P>{
        private C child;
        public Orange(P parent, C child) {
            super(parent);
            this.child = child;
        }

        public void name(){
            System.out.println("i am Orange class witha value of "+child);
        }
    }
    public class TuplePolyMorphism {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Fruits<String> fruit=new Fruits<String>("Fruit Family");
            Orange<Integer,String> orange=new Orange<>(45, "child");

            /*eclipse suggestion to rectify the above compile time error
               Orange<String, Integer> orange=new Orange<>(45, "child");
           */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the parameters on the constructor:

Either:

```
  Orange<Integer,String> orange=new Orange<>("child", 45);
```

Or:

```
public Orange(C child, P parent) { ..
```

Otherwise the types don't line up.

Full explanation: You have defined the type `Orange<C, P>` and instantiated it as `Orange<Integer, String>`, so C=Integer and P=String. The constructor is `Orange(P parent, C child)`, so it expects a String and then an Integer.

Comment: But,am passing the argument as String and Integer and if i have to,could you quote what is the reason behind?